# IIS redirect rule not working

Tags: redirect, iis, web-config

```
<rule name="Directories The" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^Directories/The" />
    <action type="Redirect" url="/" />
</rule>`
```

I have two url like this www.mydomain/Directories/the and www.mydomain/Directories/the-hindu. But i only want to redirect first url only. If i put above code two urls are redirecting.

I tried with exact match and wild card also not working. I dont want www.mydomain/Directories/the-hindu to my home page

`

Comment: https://blog.lextudio.com/iis-url-rewrite-tip-break-free-adccdb4b9f2f Improve your regular expression or build two rules. Be warned that someone might down vote you as http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your regexp `^Directories/The` is matching for both URLs:

- www.mydomain/Directories/the
- www.mydomain/Directories/the-hindu

You need to add the end of string condition to your regexp. The correct rule should be:

```
<rule name="Directories The" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^Directories/The$" />
    <action type="Redirect" url="/" />
</rule>`
```

And this rule will match only `www.mydomain/Directories/the`